# Ancora de rolagem

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Bom dia,

estou tentando fazer um indice clicavel com rolagem em meu blog.

Porém o codigo que fiz não funciona quando cria a pagina, ele altera a url ao invez de ir para o ID informado. Qual seria a melhor forma de resolver isso?

Segue link da pagina de teste -> https://www.mundoinfantilstore.com.br/premium-meninos

Segue codigo:

```js
<script>
// início do plugin
// insira aqui os créditos do autor do plugin
$.extend($.easing,
{
    easeOutCirc: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c * Math.sqrt(1 - (t=t/d-1)*t) + b;
    }
});
// fim do plugin


$("a").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   var anc = this.hash;

   $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(anc).offset().top
   }, { duration: 2000, easing: 'easeOutCirc'});
});
</script>
```

```css
<style>
  a, #ancora{
   display: block;

}

a, #ancora1{
 display: block;
}

a, #ancora2{
 display: block;
}

a, #ancora3{
 display: block;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div style="float: left; display: block;"><img src="https://179028l.ha.azioncdn.net/img/2019/12/loja/17851/principal-01.jpg" /></div>
<a href="#ancora"><img src="https://179028l.ha.azioncdn.net/img/2019/12/loja/17850/principal-02.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#ancora1"><img src="https://179028l.ha.azioncdn.net/img/2019/12/loja/17849/principal-03.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#ancora2"><img src="https://179028l.ha.azioncdn.net/img/2019/12/loja/17848/principal-04.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#ancora3"><img src="https://179028l.ha.azioncdn.net/img/2019/12/loja/17847/principal-05.jpg" /></a>
<div id="ancora">div com a âncora!</div>
<p>Teste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste teste</p>
<div id="ancora1">div com a âncora!</div>
<p>Teste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste teste</p>
<div id="ancora2">div com a âncora!</div>
<p>Teste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste teste</p>
<div id="ancora3">div com a âncora!</div>
<p>Teste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste testeTeste teste teste teste teste</p>
```

Comment: Seu código está fazendo `/#ancora` e deveria ser `/premium-meninos#ancora`

Answer (score 0):

Cara usa esse exemplo aqui.
é muito simples

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('href'),
            targetOffset = $(id).offset().top;

    $('html, body').animate({ 
        scrollTop: targetOffset - 100
    }, 500);
});
```

Usei essa referencia aqui caso queira mais detalhes.
https://www.origamid.com/codex/scroll-suave-para-link-interno/